# Allow Google custom search engine to work when the site is launched without Google indexing the site for web search beforehand

Tags: google-search-console, google-programmable-search-engine

We are using Google Custom Search, and have run into an issue related to site launches.

We would like our sites searches to actually produce results on launch, and not before...

Is there anyway to have Google crawl your site and build an index without displaying the results to the wider web(on google.com)?

Comment: Actually, G's CSE will index your site extremely quickly as soon as you create the account. So launch your site, add CSE, and then depending upon your site, it should be available as quickly as realistically possible. G will fetch over 50k pages in a day, so it should not be a problem. I did this with a site that had over one million web pages and it was fully available within about a week. Cheers!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No - CSE uses Google's main index and narrows it.

Google Site Search (GSS) was a separate index solution with it's own control panel. They merged them when they switched the name to Custom Search Engine (CSE). This also merged index controls with Google Search Console.